# DNS redirect for web app in Azure app service

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service

In Azure app service, I have an URL https://www.mywebsite.com

But I wanted once any user browse for this url (https://www.mywebsite.com) they should redirect to https://yourwebsite.com.

The mywebsite.com is simple HTML content:

```
<script type=“text/JavaScript” window.onload=function (){

  Try{ var a=windows.location.hostname; if(a.includes(“.azurewebsite.net”))
…………………..
………………….
   }
```

How can I redirect the url?

As it’s a static page and does not have web.config. Can adding a web.config with redirect rule work?

Comment: I think this post could be helpful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193377/how-to-redirect-in-app-service.html, let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.replace` , it works for me.

```
if(origin.includes(".azurewebsites")){
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Test Result.

[image]

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var origin   = window.location.origin;
            console.log(origin);
            if(origin.includes(".azurewebsites")){
                window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
            }
        })
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```